# Encrypt user password with jquery and decrypt it with Clojure

Tags: java, jquery, clojure

I want to encrypt password at client side and decrypt password at server side. I am using below code in js to encrypt password for json request

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("password", "").toString();
```

Which outputs

> "U2FsdGVkX1996HeoxCde3m8JCGvIbt1PwnByR9EOb4w="

And i am using below code for decrypt password at server

```
(defn decrypt [text key]
  (let [cipher (get-cipher Cipher/DECRYPT_MODE key)]
    (String. (.doFinal cipher (debase64 text))))) 

(decrypt "password" "")
```

Which outputs

> BadPaddingException Given final block not properly padded com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal (CipherCore.java:811)

I am not getting way how to encrypt at js and decrypt at serevr please help me thanks

Comment: I moved your errors into comment blocks and added some appropriate tags. Hopefully this will help you get an answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Should you be passing the encrypted password (`"U2FsdGVkX1996HeoxCde3m8JCGvIbt1PwnByR9EOb4w="`) to the `decrypt` function instead of the string `"password"`?

Comment: thanks for your answer now i am getting an error: (decrypt "U2FsdGVkX1996HeoxCde3m8JCGvIbt1PwnByR9EOb4w=" "")
BadPaddingException Given final block not properly padded  com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal (CipherCore.java:811)